# Using pixel fonts in PIL

Tags: python, imaging

I am creating images using PIL that contain numerous exactly placed text strings.  My first attempt was to convert pixel fonts into the pil-compatible format as described [here](http://llbb.wordpress.com/2006/11/24/making-pil-font-for-python-image-library/).  For example, I download the Silkscreen font and convert it:

```
otf2bdf -p 8pt -o fonts/slkscr.bdf fonts/slkscr.ttf 
pilfont.py fonts/slkscr.bdf
```

I can then use the font in PIL like so:

```
import Image, ImageDraw, os, sys, ImageFont
im = Image.new("RGB", (40,10))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
fn = ImageFont.load('fonts/slkscr.pil')
draw.text((0,0), "Hello", font=fn)
del draw
# write to stdout
im.save(sys.stdout, "PNG")
```

However, the resulting image ([image]) does not reflect what the font [should look like](http://kottke.org/plus/type/silkscreen/).

What procedure should I be using to convert and use pixel fonts so that they render as intended?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edit: I couldnt get it to work, and after a few hours I figured out that the pilfont.py utility actually creates 2 files, a .pil and a .pdm (the bdf is only a n intermediary). You need both of these files not only the .pil -.-

Comment: For future reference, the popular [bitfontmaker](https://www.pentacom.jp/pentacom/bitfontmaker2/) ttf can be put through this process. otf2bdf can be found [here](http://sofia.nmsu.edu/~mleisher/Software/otf2bdf/) (builds just fine _with_ patch as described on website). You will have to fidget with -p <size> but don't need to specify resolution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eureka!

Just needed to specify a resolution of 72 dpi (default is 100) for otf2bdf:

```
otf2bdf -p 8 -r 72 -o fonts/slkscr.bdf fonts/slkscr.ttf
```

Now, [image] looks great!

Comment: Do you know why that is?  It doesn't seem logical that fewer dots per inch would give you a better resolution/rendering.

Comment: It's just a question of what size in points the font arbitrarily decides to match to a pixel. Silkscreen chose 72dpi as it is the old-school Mac OS resolution.

Comment: How can I see that Silkscreen uses 72dpi? Is that visible anywhere in the file?

Comment: Do not recall, as this was quite a while ago! Knowing my past (and current!) self, I suspect I tried various dpi until I found one that worked!