# Generating an image-report with Python

Tags: python, image, text, python-imaging-library

Hy, 
I'm working on a project, where I have to generate a image (e.g. .png, .bmp etc) with a python script.

The Image must have:

1. Small boxes (8x8px) in 3 different colours
2. Horizontal(normal) text in 2 different sizes
   and 3) vertikal text (rotate normal text) (like this: http://devcity.net/Data/ArticleImages/Dual_Labels.jpg)
   So not very complex things.

I spent the last days with PiL (Python Image Library). For the small boxes, it works fine and easy. But to generate a text in the image, it doesn't work fine.

What also works is to write a normal text, with the standard font (pilfont-type).
But I can't set the px-size of this text. When using truetypes, the following error comes:
"The _imagingft C module is not installed"

I allready "googled" this and this seems to be a popular problem. My Problem is, that the script also has to run on other python systems. What I can accept is, that I have to install Pil on each system/computer, but I can't fix the problem with the truetypes each time!
I'm using Python 2.7 with pil 1.1.7.

So to my question:
For the named "forms" my script has to generate, what library (or other ways to generate an image with a script) would you recomment to me?

Would it be possible to create, e.g writing a bitmap-file with text and pixels with colour, with my script in "Pure-Python", so without any extension?(Would be the optimal solution for me)

Comment: See answer to question [Using fonts in PIL without freetype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384838/using-fonts-in-pil-without-freetype).

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using [PyCairo](http://cairographics.org/pycairo/) instead?  See this link for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6506825/514031

Answer (score 0):

This is not quite what `matplotlib` was designed for, but is definitely capable of producing what you're after. Have a look at the [gallery](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/pcolor_small.html), it has usage examples for almost everything you mentioned.