# How to prepare a FreeType PIL/Pillow package for heroku and django?

Tags: python, django, heroku, python-imaging-library

I know that this question has probably being asked several times, but so far none of the answers was addressing my specific problem.

I'm going to deploy a django application on Heroku; it needs to draw some text on an image and then display it to the user. The text will be in italian, meaning that unicode support is mandatory.

I'm encountering several problems:

- To use a ttf font i would need to provide the freetype library before installing PIL/Pillow
- [If i use a pil font file (otf -> bdf -> pil)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12388342/1237531), when PIL draws a non-ascii text i get a UnicodeEncodeError

A solution to one (or both) problem will resolve my issue:

- How to deploy PIL/Pillow on heroku with FreeType support
- How to draw non-ascii chars using PIL fonts

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this PIL fork at your requirements.txt on heroku with FreeType support:

```
-e git://github.com/errkk/gitpil.git#egg=PIL
Pillow==1.7.8
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but for me it doesn't work, the setup.py displays "*** FREETYPE2 support not available". I'm inside virtual_env, as suggested by the Heroku django tutorial.

Comment: I do mistake, please try again with new answer above.

Comment: It does the trick to load a FreeType font, but it is still impossible to complete the load of an image. I get a "DecodeError: decoder zip not available". That is strange, since during pip installation i've got "--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available". Any ideas?

Comment: For now i am using GIFs, which is the only format supported by this weird installation...

Comment: perhaps uninstall previous PIL/Pillow by using command: "heroku run pip uninstall PIL Pillow" & then install the fork again.